# .NET Core Web API project build fails on the CI server

Tags: asp.net-core, continuous-integration, asp.net-web-api2, .net-framework-version

I have a web.api project built on ASP.NET Core, with the target framework set to .NET Framework 4.6.1. Also, there's a class library project which is referenced by the Web API and its target framework is set to .NET Standard 2.0. The project builds and I can access the API fine in my local server (Visual Studio IIS Express), but when I try to build the project on the CI server, I get the following error:

> Project 'xxx.csproj' targets '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'. in CI server

How do I resolve this issue?

UPDATE:
As Chris suggested, I upgraded VS build tools to 15.5 (the latest). Then I got a series of errors as follows:

1) The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.

2) The attribute "Version" in element  is unrecognized.

3) The target "Clean" does not exist in the project.

First two - I got rid of them by modifying the csproj file (though I'm not sure if it's necessary?) I'm still stuck with the 3rd one.

Comment: Provide more information. What build server you use? What's installed on it? Linux or Windows? msbuild or dotnet for building?

Comment: it's Windows and TFS, and uses msbuild.

Answer (score 0):

There's really not enough here to actually diagnose the issue, but my best guess is that you're missing the .NET Core 2.0 SDK on the build server. .NET Standard 2.0 is not compatible with .NET Framework 4.6.1 without the .NET Core 2.0 SDK.

Comment: I did install .NET Core 2.0 SDK on the build server. But I will double check and perhaps reinstall.

Comment: Make sure it's the SDK and not the runtime. It's a common mistake, especially if you're moving quick and not paying close attention to what you're downloading.

Comment: I do have SDK 2.1.4 installed on the build server.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the visual studio version? I have seen several threads which suggest to install visual studio 2017 update 3, but I assume it's for those who get the issue on VS build. We do have VS 2017 15.3.2

Comment: Actually, I just found a closed issue related to this, and it seems you do need 15.4+ build tools.

Comment: Actually, that seem to be the case, but after I upgraded VS to 15.5, I'm getting a different set of errors. Posted them under the initial question.